# Create bitmap after selecting image from Photo application in android

Tags: android, bitmap

We have got following FilePath 
fileUri: content://com.google.android.apps.photos.content/0/https%3A%2F%2Flh3.googleusercontent.com%2FxXsZw6C7QABlFZbEqzd1c5qjiAAkpQtnlyESHDY9xl4%3Ds0-d

This image is synced on the device through cloud.

We got this filepath either from getContentResolver() or CursorLoader

But we could not able to convert it into Bitmap object

Any idea to covert this kind of file path into Bitmap using FileInputStream

Comment: try downloading the url, https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/xXsZw6C7QABlFZbEqzd1c5qjiAAkpQtnlyESHDY9xl4=s0-d

Comment: Yes you are right, but i do not want to download the image over the network, As it exists on my device. if there is no way to read image from the device due to restriction imposed by the Photo application, then i will accept your answer and will implement by downloading the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can read in the FileInputStream into a byte[] and then do a BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byte[] input param, offset, length of byte[]), to create a bitmap out of it.

Refer this link for more details - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray(byte[],int,int,android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options)

There are other options in the BitmapFactory as well, which you may want to try, depending on what you intend to do.

Hope this helps.